# When is the word "Departure" countable or uncountable?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

When is "Departure" a countable usage and when is it not?

Comment: It's countable when it refers to specific events. "The bus to X has 5 departures per day."

Comment: The test for a count usage that CGEL recommends (and Weather Vane uses above) is whether or not a numeral may be inserted. While I agree that this is probably the best test available, it still has grey areas. Does 'Both amount to radical departures from existing US foreign policy.' ([Times; Collins CoBuild](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/radical-departure)) license '[T]here were two radical departures'? I'd certainly shy away from 'There were 17 radical departures' but not 'several radical departures'. / But terminology perhaps is **un**helpful here. What is _acceptable_?

Comment: To paraphrase Weather Vane, it's countable when you can count 'em, and non-countable when you can't.

Answer (score 1):

There is some disagreement between dictionaries about whether the noun "departure" can be uncountable or not. Cambridge says it is countable, Mirriam-Webster doesn't say (which I assume means it defaults to countable). Only Wiktionary and Oxford learners say it can be uncountable.

The only example I can find in the dictionaries that would seem be fit 'uncountable" is where it is used to refer to a part of many events, for example:

> You must check in at least one hour before departure.

Here "departure" doesn't refer to a single event but is used to refer to implicitly one of many departures. Other dictionaries quote similar structures but consider the noun singular or countable.

Comment: Departure from established financial policy is frowned upon where I work.

Answer (score 0):

[OALD {adjusted}](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/radical-departure) has (perhaps wisely, but not over-helpfully)

> **departure** noun ​  [countable, uncountable]
>
> **1** an act of leaving a place
>
> - a *His sudden departure threw the office into chaos.*
> - b *rumours of her imminent/impending departure*
>
>   - c departure from… *They had received no news of him since his departure from the island.*
>   - d departure for… *The day of their departure for London was growing closer.*
>   - e departure to… *She postponed her departure to Scotland.*
> - f before departure: *Flights should be confirmed 48 hours before departure.*

Using one of the tests for count usages that CGEL advocates [can a numeral (or equivalent, eg 'several', 'a dozen' {not just a quantifier such as 'a' or 'some'}) be inserted with this usage?], I'd say that none of the above are often used with numerals, so I can see the reason behind OALD's decision not to plump for one or the other here.

Though the count usage with this sense is rare, these examples are reasonable:

- *Several departures seemed over-hasty, thought Pierow.*
- *There are three impending departures from the company.* [a metaphorical broadening, as is 1a]

OALD continues:

> [countable]
>
> ​  **2** a plane, train, etc. leaving a place at a particular
>   time
>
> - a *arrivals and departures*
> - b *All departures are from Manchester*.
>
>   - c *We sat in the departure lounge waiting for our flight to be called.*
>   - d *the departure time/gate*
>   - e *the departures board*

The attributive usages c-e don't really come into the count–non-count categorisation, but note the use of the plural form as well as the singular. 'Arrivals and departures' is really a fixed phrase, so again outside count–non-count categorisation, but of course 'There were 5 arrivals and 6 departures' is fine.

> **departures** [uncountable]
>
> **3** the part of an airport where you go before catching a plane
>
> - *There were long delays and queues in departures.*

If a meta-plural is required here, we'd have to use either the ordinary plural form  'There were problems in *departures* in all three terminals', or '... in all three departure lounges'.

> ​[countable]
>
> **4** an action that is different from what is usual or expected
>
> - *Their latest single represents a new departure for the band.*
>
>   - departure from something *It was a radical departure from tradition.*

Though 'several' can be inserted here, numerals would be rare. But then again, though 'a radical departure from' ... may be achieving idiom status, pluralisation does not sound too unnatural, and doubtless the count designation is correct.